# Electron.js integration with Angular 6+

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

To make desktop app from Angular build we have to create `main` property in the `package.json` file to define the path to the Electron starting script. But Angular 6+ allows to keep 1+ projects in workspace, so I have only one package.json file, only one node_modules folder, etc since stack is the same, the only difference is the Electron scripts.

So, the question is - can I set path to `main.js` file for Electron dynamically? For example, with terminal command. For now I know only about dynamic path to `index.html` file like:

```
electron ./projects/launcher/build/index.html
```

Any idea?

Comment: why do you think that you can have more than 1 angular project with the same package.json, node_modules, etc? the package.json defines the project

Comment: Learn Angular docs, please. Angular 6+ allows you to create more then 1 Angular project that will use the same base (property "projects" in angular.json file). You can create as many projects as you want to and they will use your node_modules folder, package.json file etc.

Comment: can you please provide that link then? as looking over the docs, i cant see where your argument is supported

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/glossary#workspace

Comment: that just says you can have multiple projects in a workspace (which i already knew), it doesnt say about sharing the same package.json and node modules

Comment: What do you mean? Each project in Angular 6+ is like a "src" folder in Angular < 6v, do you keep package.json, node_modules etc within each project folder??

Comment: the project is the whole project folder, so you have a folder which is the project name, then within that you have the package.json, node_modules, src, etc. the project is the `ProjectName` folder, not the `src` folder

Comment: So if you have 2+ projects with the same dependencies, you still keep hardcoded dependencies, the same node_modules folder. Isn't it a bad way of programming? Framework allows you to have one node_modules folder, one list of dependencies, environment, etc, without copy-paste and hardcode, why shouldn't I use it?

Comment: for the moment, you cant have one copy of node_modules, there isnt a global way of storing them on your computer in a place where any project can access them. hopefully this will change in the future

Comment: Well, I have Angular base with only one package.json, node_modules, common classes to extend in the workspace projects, what am I doing wrong? Again, I have the same stack for all workspace projects, that's the correct way, without copy-paste and hardcode, one place for all common things. Framework straightly allows it.

Comment: having multiple project in a workspace is fine, but you claim to have multiple projects in a project

Comment: Projects with the same base -> workspace projects, no?

Comment: a workspace is just a collection of projects, a workspace folder will have multiple project folders inside

Comment: We just back to the beginning - I have the same stack for all workspace projects, so I keep dependencies list in the workspace root, so one node_modules folder, one env, etc, to not copy-paste the same files from project to project. That's the right approach. Now the question - can I set path to Electron's main.js file dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file for each project and open a [BrowserWindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) and load -[`BrowserWindowInstance.loadURL`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winloadurlurl-options)- it. Then you will have your electron applications.

Besides that, in the build process, you may update the main property in package.json and build the application.